# How can I print to OneNote without splitting the document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2013

I've noticed with longer pdf's, after sending to OneNote with Print and selecting a Page to insert to, OneNote ends up splitting my document into its own page and subpages (1 for each page).  I want the whole document on the page that I select instead of having it split like that.  It inserts everything to one page when my pdf is 4 pages long, but splits it when I have 6 pages, so I'm assuming the cutoff is at 5 pages or something.  How can I disable this behavior?

Edit: Forgot to mention this is in OneNote 2013 in case the behavior is different across versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out there's an advanced option for it. File > Options > Advanced > Insert long printouts on multiple pages.